# Controlling Text Size for posters

Tags: posters, text

I'm using Latex to make an A1 professional poster.
As such; I need to be able to control/change the size of the text throughout the poster, setting some parts are larger and some smaller.
I had been using /Huge{} and similar commands to make chunks of text large - but this is too small for the poster size. Is there a package that will allow me to control text in a similar way?

Comment: you don't need a package `\fontsize{3cm}{3.2cm}\selectfont` will set 3cm high letters which should be big enough. (if using cm fonts, add `fix-cm` package)

Comment: I use the `memoir` class for posters, because of the many font sizes it supports.